# Trying to hide/disable entire menu (overflow) in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-menu

I have been unsuccessful in trying to hide or disable the `overflow menu` in one `fragment`.

I have tried setting `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` with no success, and then I tried `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and tried inflating with an empty menu like below.

Both attempts do not work for me.

**How do I hide or disable the options/overflow menu in one fragment only??**

Thanks in advance!

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.empty, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Are you mistaking fragment with activity?

Comment: @PozzoApps nope. I want to change the options menu only in a certain fragment. I figured out how to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured out how to do it. Just need to set the menu items I don't want visible. In my case, I set all of them not visible and that removed the overflow menu entirely.

Also don't forget you have to `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your `onCreate` so it knows to call `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    if (menu != null) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_leave_feedback).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_shop).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is very late but I like to share it.
In Fragment onCreate method:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
```

And in Fragment onCreateOptionsMenu() method:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        menu.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

in OnCreate() and

```
 @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items       
                menu.findItem(R.id.xxx).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.yyy).setVisible(false);              
        }
```