# Hide MenuItem in one Fragment in FragmentActivity with swipe tabs functionality

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem

I've a FragmentActivity with three swipe tabs. I've added a REFRESH Icon as MenuItem in actionbar and inflated that menu in FragmentActivity by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu.

```html
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.live_stream_item, menu);
  refreshMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.getItem(0);
  refreshMenuItem.setVisible(true);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

I've globally declared refreshMenuItem and wanted to set Visibility GONE refreshMenuItem.setVisible(false) in one fragment and make it visible in other fragments.

I've used setHasOptionsMenu in one fragment where I want refresh menu item Invisible.

```html
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

Even I tried to set that refreshMenuItem.setVisible(false) in setUserVisibleHint in that particular fragment to hide this menuItem.

Nothing works.....Please help me out.

Comment: Try this stackover link  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538422/trying-to-hide-disable-entire-menu-overflow-in-fragment][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538422/trying-to-hide-disable-entire-menu-overflow-in-fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set setHasOptionsMenu(true) in Fragment's onCreate method and 
override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in the fragment and set the visibility of the corresponding menu item.

```
 @Override
 void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items       
          menu.findItem(R.id.xxx).setVisible(false);
          menu.findItem(R.id.yyy).setVisible(false);              
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. setHasOptionsMenu(true) in Fragment's onCreate method along with your code snippet worked perfectly.